# Saving excel file as other name

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to save an excel with other name.

```
WB.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Output\" + "Family" + @"\Item_" + entry.Key + ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,false, true, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

but if the entry.key is equal to `599, 863,868,875,868,881,882,902,` then I am getting an error saying

> ExportData  Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\Naveen\Tool\bin\Debug\Output\Family\1CF3EF00'. There are several
>   possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

`"1CF3EF00"` this part is getting changed every time I run the code.

eg: `09E7EF00,E748EF00` etc

Comment: What is the data type of entry.Key?
Why are you not seeing 'C:\Naveen\Tool\bin\Debug\Output\Family
Item_ prefix and .xlsx extension in the exception?
What happens if you replace item.key with some string "foo"? Would that work? Lets start there and debug forward

Comment: Data Type of entry.key is string.

Comment: Tried replacing entry.key with some string. But not working. Getting same error

Comment: It might be the space between "599, 863,"

Comment: No. Actually I want a separate excel workbook for 599, 863 etc.

Comment: Can you humor me by showing the contents of `entry` or the code that populates it?  It's a `Dictionary<string,T>` ?

Comment: Its Dictionary<string,string>.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error if you specify another directory? like the temp?          `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Item_" + entry.Key + ".xlsx"`

Comment: I am saving before closing the workbook. The code is working for entry.key other than 599, 863,868,875,868,881,882,902 these.